# JsonConvert on a list not returning what I'm looking for

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a .NET 4.5 application. Currently I am writing a list, which is outputted to an XML file:

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]> { };

list.Add(new string[] { "text1", "this is text 1" });
list.Add(new string[] { "text2", "this is text 2" });
list.Add(new string[] { "text3", "this is text 3" });
list.Add(new string[] { "text4", "this is text 4" });

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("texts");

    foreach (string[] item in list)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString(item[0], item[1]);
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

The output of this returns as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<texts>
    <text1>this is text 1</text1>
    <text2>this is text 2</text2>
    <text3>this is text 3</text3>
    <text4>this is text 4</text4>
</texts>
```

Running `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` on this list returns the following:

```
[
    ["text1", "this is text 1"],
    ["text2", "this is text 2"],
    ["text3", "this is text 3"],
    ["text4", "this is text 4"]
]
```

Naturally, this is not that useful. Something more useful would be:

```
{
  "text1": "this is text 1",
  "text2": "this is text 2",
  "text3": "this is text 3",
  "text4": "this is text 4"
}
```

What would be the best way to get this done?

Comment: You error is that you create a list of string arrays in c#. To get your result you need an object with the properties `text1, text2, ...`. And than you can run JsonConvert on this object.

Comment: It's treating the array as a row.  It will always comma-delimit columns in a row. You need to go about it differently to get that output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list.ToDictionary(p => p[0], p => p[1]))`

Or you can write your own custom `JsonConverter`

**UPD**: As @Equalsk pointed out this code (without custom converter) will work only if first items in string arrays are unique (text1, text2, etc.)

Comment: OP should be aware that this only works if the [0] array strings are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary instead of list to get your result. If you have only key-value pairs use Dictionary. If more you can use Tuple. If not wrap it up and write your own custom Converter.